# How to fix error with toUpperCase?

Tags: angularjs

I have variable in Angular JS:

```
$scope.formData.time
```

That contains format: `"12:00:00"`

I have filter:

```
.filter('timeApp', function ($filter) {
            return function (input) {
                if (input == null) {
                    return "";
                }

                var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'HH:mm:ss');
                return _date.toUpperCase();

            }
        })
```

When I call this filter for `$scope.formData.time`:

```
$scope.formData.time = $filter('timeApp')($scope.formData.time);
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: _date.toUpperCase is not a function at line 

return _date.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: Why you hant to call toUpperCase on a dateField? Make this sence?

Comment: why are you calling toUppercase on a date ? what are you trying to do ? : )

Comment: filter will return date not string.. date doesn't have any `toUpperCase` method

Comment: no, it returns string, like `14:49:15`

Comment: actually when `$filter('date')(new Date(input), 'HH:mm:ss');` is passed `input` as `undefined` it returns an object which does not have function `toUpperCase`, if you do an alert like `alert(_date)` it will say `Invalid date` which is because this object has `toSting()` method which shows `Invalid Date` but it itself has no method `toUpperCase()`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this line is correct or not

```
 var _date = $filter('date')(new Date(input), 'HH:mm:ss');
```

but other possible error can be that you are only cheching for `null'
do something like

```
if (input)
```

instead of

```
if (input == null)
```

Comment: *checking, sorry about typo

Comment: The `input` isn not empty. It contents `Thu Jan 01 1970 13:00:00 GMT+0400`

Comment: then before calling `toUpperCase` check the type of `_date` like `if (typeof(_date) != 'string') { //do somethong }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still relevant but I had the same problem and this what help for me:

instead of

```
if (input == null)
```

use:

```
if(input == null || input == "0000-00-00" || input == "0000-00-00 00:00:00"){ return ""; }
```